# DynamoDB NewImage stream doesn't return all fields

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a dynamodb stream to trigger a lambda function. On invocation the lambda function looks for three fields from the dynamodb event.

ID (PK)
Name
Location

When my Lambda receives a MODIFY event all three of these fields are populated. However, when it receives an INSERT event only id is populated. I can always query again for the rest of the fields, but why aren't they populated when I receive the event?

DynamoDB stream is set to "newimage", if it matters I am adding new items through the console. I'm also noticing that if I try to update those items later on the event type is still "INSERT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by deleting and readding the stream on the lambda, not sure exactly what caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by disabling and re-enabling the stream on the Dynamo Db via the Manage Stream

[image]